# What is mean by oAuth type "access" or "verifier" in Magento2?

Tags: api, oauth, key

In oauth_token table, what/how records are associated with "consumer_id" or "admin_id" ? I created a profile in system > integration , and that recordd has consumer_id but not admin_id

Also, what's  the meaning of "type"? I see on my table , there are both "access" & "verifier".

[image]